# How do I sort a playlist by filename in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, playlist

I want to import an audiobook where there are 14 folders on the form "Author - CD ## - Title", and the mp3-files are on the form "### - Author - Title" (incrementally over all CDs, so the last file of 'CD 01' is named '012...", and the first file of 'CD 02' is named '013...'.

However, the ID3 tag stupidly consist of "Title = Author", and nothing else. And when imported the files are scattered around randomly in the playlist.

How do I sort a playlist by filename?

or; How do I remove the ID3-tags of a folder of folders of mp3-files on Mac easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st sort column is sorted by when the file was added to the playlist. If you can drag them into the playlist in the order you want...you are set

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this is not possible. As there isn't a column available for filename, one can't sort by it.

If you're willing to take the time, you can input the metadata and sort by track number. You'd only really need to enter the track numbers incrementally (like the file names), but you might instead choose to number the tracks per disk and then input which disk they're on as well. This way would need to be sorted by Album rather than track number, as it would otherwise go 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,… rather than 1,2,3,…1,2,3,…1,2,3,….

Sorry it's so inconvenient, but I hope this works for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you drag a folder on a playlist from Finder and sort the playlist by the first column, the items are usually sorted by filename.

You might also run a script like this in AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "iTunes" to repeat with t in (get selection)
    set comment of t to POSIX path of (get location of t)
end repeat
```

Then sort the tracks by the comment field.

To delete all tags, run `sudo easy_install pip;sudo pip install mutagen`, then run something like `for f in *.mp3;do mid3v2 --delete-all "$f";done`, and then tell iTunes to update the tags by selecting the items and running `tell app "iTunes" to refresh selection`.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 8.1, this works for me:

1. Create new playlist in iTunes
2. Find files in Windows Explorer
3. Ctrl-A to select all files
4. Drag files into iTunes - **ensuring that the drag point is from the first file in the list**.

If you drag from mid way down the file list, you get unexpected file ordering.
I'm surprised this works but it does seem repeatable.